# pytest mock os.listdir to return empty list

Tags: python, pytest

I have a function in my program that list all the files in a given path and I am trying to write a test that passes when there are no files exists in the path provided (empty output i.e `[]`) I am learning about mocker fixture of `pytest` to do it. Here is what i have written,

```
def test_no_dirs(mocker):
    mocker.patch('os.listdir')
    assert get_list() #get_list returns ['abc.json', 'test.json', 'test2.json']
    os.listdir.assert_called_with('/etc/app_data/',stdout=[])
```

I have used mocker as a parameter first then patch the `os.listdir` function. `os.listdir` is called in `get_list()`, but i don't know how to change the `return` value of `os.listdir` to empty list, `[]` to mock empty directory.

When I run above command I get the following error,

```
E       AssertionError: Expected call: listdir('/etc/app_data/', stdout='[]')
E       Actual call: listdir('/etc/app_data/')
E
E       pytest introspection follows:
E
E       Kwargs:
E       assert {} == {'stdout': '[]'}
E         Right contains more items:
E         {'stdout': '[]'}
E         Full diff:
E         - {}
E         + {'stdout': '[]'}
```

How can I mock `os.listdir` to return empty value and pass the test?

If i remove `stdout=[]`, the test `PASS` but its not really doing what i want to do, which is to pass when there are no files.

That's the code for `get_list()`

```
import os
def get_list():
    return os.listdir('/etc/app_data/')
```

Comment: Add the code for `get_list`.  We need to see how `listdir` is used/imported.

Comment: I have added the code @wim thanks

Comment: Why are you passing `stdout=[]` to `assert_called_with`? You're asserting that `stdout=[]` was one of the keyword arguments to the `listdir` call, when no such argument was passed.

Comment: i was watching online tutorial or pytest. and that's how they suggest to set `stdout` value, i must have confused it. thanks for clearing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pytest-mock` version should look something like this:

```
def test_no_dirs(mocker):
    mock = mocker.patch('os.listdir', return_value=[])
    result = get_list()
    assert result == []  # because that's the `return_value` mocked
    mock.assert_called_once_with('/etc/app_data/')
```

Note that users who do `from os import listdir` will need to mock in a different namespace!

Comment: thank you so much. can you please suggest where can i find good documentation on `pytest-mock` which is easy to understand ?

Comment: The stdlib documentation for [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).  Note that `mocker` fixture just injects mock namespace.